# PDO "SELECT" not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get PDO to return the results of a wildcard search. My code is:

```
$search = "%Notes%"; 
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE 'name' LIKE :search");
$result->bindParam(':search', $search);

$result->execute();

while($arr = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $arr['name'];
}
```

At the moment, I get a blank screen. If I run the sequel through PHPMyAdmin:

> SELECT * FROM  `books` WHERE  `name` LIKE  '%Notes%'

I get the appropriate result.

I assume it's something to do with the way I am formatting my PDO statement, I know you can't have a dynamic column name but I don't see what is going wrong?

Comment: try moving the % to the query and bind just `Notes`

Comment: Throws a syntax error then

Comment: name has quotes around it. thats invalid make it backticks

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell
Me being stupid...

Comment: sure thing I made it an answer so we can close it

Comment: when you can if you can mark the answer as accepted I'd greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93629/discussion-between-unk-and-john-ruddell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your query you have `'name'` change that to just backticks instead of quotes

aka

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `name` LIKE :search");
```

you can also just remove the backticks